# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful biking resources and websites
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/861).

Comment: Anybody want to update our [old League of American Bicyclists Ad](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/778/community-promotion-ads-2013/780#780) with [their new logo](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7ckw7gxdbm5t48d/e5jUtnaQ3P)?

Comment: @freiheit Done.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Sheldon Brown's Bicycle Technical Info]

Comment: +1, Banner could be improved, though

Comment: @Papauss It was built to match their site.

Comment: Yes it looks like that button broke out of the 90s Robin Williams style, all "what year is it?" and "we have to finish the game!" Can we get a nicer looking button?

Answer (score 7):

[image: Park Tool's Repair Help and Education]

Comment: I'm really torn about whether or not to vote this one up...  It's an awesome reference site, but it is basically a commercial site... Definitely a nicely done image, though.

Comment: @freiheit I actually felt the same way when I saw the pixelated one below. I do see people link to it all the time on our site though, so I decided to put up a decent version of the logo. I really don't feel strongly about whether or not it should be an ad on our site. I'm a bit disappointed Sheldon's ad hasn't gotten more votes though.

Comment: on their defense, the articles do mention their tools, but never word the steps as if their brand is essential. in fact the last article i read, about derailleur adjustment, it barely show any tools at all! i give them a vote of confidence (and my occasional business) for that. Maybe balance that by making the fact that there is How To articles more than the brand?

Comment: I have deleted my post on the topic. I think its a good reference site, and they do publish a book on it as well. The link isn't to the sales portion of the site, and I don't see listing compatible tools as really a problem, especially since they describe the tools typically with "such as" (one can always comparison shop anyway).

Answer (score 7):

[image: View the latest blog posts from the Bicycles Stack Exchange community!]

Comment: Copied from the one NeilFein and nhinkle did [last year](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/781

Answer (score 6):

[image: @StackBicycles]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: The time posting on twitter could be used answering questions here.

Comment: @gcb the twitter account is completely automatic, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 5):

[image: The League of American Bicyclists]

Comment: I have nothing against it, but as an European I see this only partly useful.

Comment: @Papuass Do you have a bicycle advocacy group in Europe that fills the same role? If so, I'd be more than happy to build an ad for them too.

Answer (score 4):

[image: A site for bike light reviews, beamshots, technical information, and advice. Created by a Stack Exchange Bicycles user!]

Comment: This is a pretty awesome resource that started out as a series of posts on the bicycles.se blog.