# Lower threshold for community promotion ads?

Tags: discussion

Meta has been quiet lately and the [Community Promotion Ads](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/861/community-promotion-ads-2014) seem to have been forgotten. Should we consider lowering the threshold for what gets displayed to four or five votes? And is that even possible?

Comment: It figures that I post this and people start voting again.

Comment: I support this. Despite this meta post, there's still only 1 approved community ad.